# How can I use the fastest method to group the dataframe and generate a column as a sequence of numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I use the fastest method to group the dataframe and generate a column as a sequence of numbers?
My code steps are as follows:

1. First generate the date dataframe `date`
2. Generate `code` dataframe
3. Generate the `Cartesian product` df of `date` and `code`
4. Delete redundant columns `['a','level_1','order']`
5. Group according to the `date` column, and generate an `order` column in the order of `values` within each group

my question:

1. These steps feel too cumbersome, is there an easy way?
2. How to avoid generation of `level_1` and `order` columns in the fourth step
3. How to optimize the code, it takes 5 seconds to execute it now

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def add_order(df):
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True).reset_index()
    df = df.drop(columns='date')
    return df


def generate_data():
    np.random.seed(202107)
    date = pd.date_range(start='20150101', end='20210723', freq='D')
    date = date.to_pydatetime()
    date = np.vectorize(lambda s: s.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))(date)
    date = pd.DataFrame(date, columns=['date'])
    date['a'] = 1

    code = pd.DataFrame(range(50), columns=['code'])
    code['a'] = 1

    df = pd.merge(date, code, how='outer')
    df['value'] = np.random.random(len(df)) * 1000

    return df


def get_result(df):
    df = df.sort_values(by='value', ascending=False)
    df = df.groupby('date').apply(add_order)
    df = df.reset_index().sort_values(by=['date', 'code']).reset_index(drop=True)
    df = df.rename(columns={'index': 'order'})
    col = ['date', 'code', 'value', 'order']
    df = df[col]
    # print(df)
    return df


def main():
    df = generate_data()
    df = get_result(df)
```

```
%timeit main()
5.25 s ± 130 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The result is:

```
              date  code       value  order
0       2015-01-01     0  227.190649     39
1       2015-01-01     1  543.938036     26
2       2015-01-01     2  175.707748     43
3       2015-01-01     3  789.146427      9
4       2015-01-01     4  585.727841     24
...            ...   ...         ...    ...
119795  2021-07-23    45   92.698866     43
119796  2021-07-23    46  111.500843     40
119797  2021-07-23    47  700.675634     12
119798  2021-07-23    48  933.134534      4
119799  2021-07-23    49  108.004811     42
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're looking to do. I'm also not sure which of these values are generated to perform the computations and which are the starting values for the problem. Do we start with `df`? Do we start with `date` and `code`? Just `date`?

Comment: Do you want *product* of columns `date` and `code` and for each date group add ascending values?

Comment: @HenryEckerI modified my code and divided it into two functions: generate_data and get_result. Both generate_data and get_result need to be optimized

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the `a` column is unnecessary, so the generation can become something like:

```
def generate_data_mod():
    np.random.seed(202107)
    df = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [pd.date_range(
            start='20150101', end='20210723', freq='D'
        ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
         np.arange(50)],
        names=['date', 'code']
    ).to_frame(index=False)
    df['value'] = np.random.random(len(df)) * 1000
    # df['a'] = 1  # (If it is needed)
    return df
```

Then we can use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by `value`. Then use [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) to enumerate groups. Then [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to restore order:

```
def get_result_mod(df):
    # df = df.drop(columns='a')  # If df has the a column
    df = df.sort_values(by='value', ascending=False)
    df['order'] = df.groupby('date').cumcount()
    df = df.sort_index()
    return df
```

Sanity Checks:

```
def main():
    df = generate_data()
    df_mod = generate_data_mod()
    # True (note df_mod has no A column)
    print(df.drop(columns='a').eq(df_mod).all(None))
    # True
    print(get_result(df).eq(get_result_mod(df_mod)).all(None))
```

Timing Information:

Generate Data is about the same (`merge` is very efficient):

```
%timeit generate_data()
21 ms ± 507 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit generate_data_mod()
20.2 ms ± 428 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

get_result is *much* faster this way:

```
df = generate_data()

%timeit get_result(df)
1.77 s ± 28.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit get_result_mod(df)
51 ms ± 4.17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I've understood your question right, but based on your comments:

```py
from itertools import product

date = pd.date_range(start="20150101", end="20210723", freq="D")
date = pd.DataFrame(date, columns=["date"])

code = pd.DataFrame(range(50), columns=["code"])

# generate product of the two columns:
df = pd.DataFrame(product(date["date"], code["code"]), columns=["date", "code"])

# to each "date group" add ascending random values
g = df.groupby("date")

df["value"] = g.transform(lambda x: np.random.random(len(x)) * 1000)
df["order"] = g["value"].transform(np.argsort)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
             date  code       value  order
0      2015-01-01     0   72.380011     26
1      2015-01-01     1  888.644908     42
2      2015-01-01     2  205.610256     40
3      2015-01-01     3  425.763108     16
4      2015-01-01     4  198.628891      0
5      2015-01-01     5  659.725661     34

...

119795 2021-07-23    45  376.110403     19
119796 2021-07-23    46  697.473751     13
119797 2021-07-23    47  615.449182     10
119798 2021-07-23    48  741.031350     39
119799 2021-07-23    49  201.422477     15
```

Comment: I revised my question and listed the results I needed.

Comment: @jaried I've updated my code. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes. It's I want.